# How to remove the index values from a json object

Tags: node.js, json

How to remove the array index values from a json object

I have tried to use stringify but couldn't get the expected result.

```
{
  "header":{"test":"test1", "test2":"test2"},
  "results_1":{"a":"b"},
  "results_2":{"0":{"id1":"1", "value1" :1}, "1":{"id2":"2", "value2":2 }}
}
```

I need to conver this to

```
{
  "header":{"test":"test1", "test2":"test2"},
  "results_1":{"a":"b"},
  "results_2":[{"id1":"1", value:1}, {"id2":"2", value:2}]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a replacer function:

```js
const o = {
  "header":{"test":"test1", "test2":"test2"},
  "results_1":{"a":"b"},
  "results_2":{"0":{"id1":"1", "value1" :1}, "1":{"id2":"2", "value2":2 }}
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(o, (k, v) => {
  if (
    typeof v == 'object' &&
    !Array.isArray(v) && 
    v.hasOwnProperty(0) 
  ) { return Object.values(v); }
  else { return v; }
}));
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response.. Is there a way to write a more generic function? So i can do this for any existing arrays that we will pass

Comment: Well, you'd have to use some heuristics, updated my answer